# Ember: how to create a join table model using Rails API

Tags: ember-data, rails-api

I'm using Rails5 API and Ember 3.
On the Rails side the model I'd like to save is defined as follows:

```
class ShopLanguage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :language
end
```

Here is the Shop model:

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop_languages, inverse_of: :shop, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :languages, through: :shop_languages
end
```

Here is the ShopLanguage serializer:

```
class ShopLanguageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :shop_id, :language_id, :modified_by
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :language
end
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to create a new `shop_language`for a specified shop from Ember:

```
# controllers/shop-languages.js
actions: {
  saveLanguage(aLanguage) {
  let shopLanguage = this.store.createRecord('shop-language', {
         language: aLanguage,
         shop: this.get('currentShop.shop'),
         modifiedBy: this.get('currentUser.user').get('username')
       });
  shopLanguage.save().then(function() {
          this.get('flashMessages').info('New language added with success');
      });
```

the `language_id` is not passed in in `params` hash in the `ShopLanguagesController` on the Rails side:

```
# shop_langauges_controller.rb
class ShopLanguagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_shop
  before_action :find_language, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @shop.languages << @language
    json_response(@shop.languages, :created)
  end

  private

  def language_params
    params.permit(:language_id, :shop_id, :id, :modified_by)
  end

  def find_shop
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  end

  def find_language
    @language = Language.find_by!(id: params[:language_id])
  end
end
```

When I check the URL hit by Ember app, it seems to be OK:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/shops/613/languages
```

The error comes from `find_language` method because `language_id` is null.
Why so ? What is wrong with that ? Thank you